# Java problems importing code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I'm importing java project in eclipse and i'm getting the following errors. In description, it gives me 'Java Problems(2 items)'. First item is as follows:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.CharSequence. Fix the build path then try building this project.
```

Second item is as follows:

```
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from the required .class files.
```

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in Eclipse about type indirectly referenced from required .class file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476092/error-in-eclipse-about-type-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-file)

Comment: Are you sure about you are using the external JDK as build path. Now  clean the project after that refresh the project.

Comment: I tried clean, refresh and restart and none of it worked. I found a difference in Access rules in JRE library. Could this be the issue? I'd 164 rules defined in my current project and none when i import it.Also, i've JRE-7 in one system and JRE-8 in the other, could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just select Project option in Eclipse and click on Clean.and then build the project

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by importing rt.jar file in my project. Thanks for all the help guys.